# Cleaning up unused images in PDF page resources

Tags: pdfbox

Please forgive me if this has been asked but I have not found any matches yet.

I have some PDF files where images are duplicated on each page's resources but never used in its content stream. I think this is causing the PDFSplit command to create very bloated pages. Is there any utility code or examples to clean up unused resources like this? Maybe a starting point for me to get going?

[image: Screenshot of the images]

Comment: I've debugged this more. The same instance (physical memory) XObject dictionary is  shared between all of these pages. I suppose this is to prevent duplication of shared resources between pages but it causes page bloat when trying to split the document.

Comment: There is no utility code for that, one would have to create something. I.e. parse the content stream to see which of the resources are used, and then clean up the resource dictionaries. Maybe I'll create something when the heat wave is over. (I can barely think at 30°)

Comment: I have something that I've been working on that is similar to what you describe. I have it identifying the unused images but I'm having problems removing them properly. Once I remove the image from one page, the images are gone from subsequent pages.

Would you mind taking a look at the stripUnusedImages method and giving me some feedback?: https://gist.github.com/SakeviYokoyama/edeaa405bea30e3c94aaba8b073aaf2f

Comment: I looked at your code and it seemed very good to me (but I didn't run it). You're really good. Can you share a PDF before and after? Btw `newObjects.setDirect(true);` seems suspicious and isn't needed IMHO. If you can't share the file I'll try to find one this weekend, temperature will go down on sunday here.

Comment: Thank you very much. The document has medical information so I cannot share it but I'll work on trying to recreate an example with test images. I suppose I'll need one for a good unit test anyway. I'll update when I have a good sample.Thanks again for the help. I hope you find some relief from the heat.

Comment: I got a PDF: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12647397/239665.pdf from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2101 .

Comment: Thanks! I think I have the problem fixed. I had assumed that the XObjects dictionary was shared between pages but it was actually the Resources dictionary that was shared. I updated the example code to copy the resources before replacing the XObjects (see copyResources method) and everything is working now. I also fixed an embarrassing typo in the arguments to stripUnusedImages.

Comment: You're really good and/or this heat really prevents me from thinking - I did notice that the resources object # in my file is the same, but didn't make any conclusion. Feel free to answer your question yourself, this is allowed, I'll upvote it. Also consider improving `Splitter.processPage()` and create an issue in JIRA.

Comment: I've been banging my head on this problem for a few days now. I'm just relieved to have made progress! I need to get this cleaned up and implemented into our product and then I'll provide an answer. I'll see if I can submit a patch for the Apache provided splitter some time next week.

Comment: For what it's worth, Fujitsu Scanners (PFU PDF Library 1.2.0/SS Manager for fi Series 1.0.7) appear to do this. I'm not sure if it's a bug/bad behavior but it definitely gave us some problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to clean up the resources for each page by gathering a list of the images used inside the page's content stream. With the list of images, I then check the resources for the page and remove any that weren't used. See the PageExtractor.stripUnusedImages below for implementation details.

The resource object was shared between pages so I also had to make sure each page had its own copy of the resource object before removing images. See PageExtractor.copyResources below for implementation details.

**The page splitter:**

```
package org.apache.pdfbox.examples;

import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.Operator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSBase;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDAction;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionGoTo;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationLink;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.destination.PDDestination;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.destination.PDPageDestination;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class PageExtractor {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public PDDocument extractPage(PDDocument source, Integer pageNumber) throws IOException {
        PDDocument targetPdf = new PDDocument();

        targetPdf.getDocument().setVersion(source.getVersion());
        targetPdf.setDocumentInformation(source.getDocumentInformation());
        targetPdf.getDocumentCatalog().setViewerPreferences(source.getDocumentCatalog().getViewerPreferences());

        PDPage sourcePage = source.getPage(pageNumber);
        PDPage targetPage = targetPdf.importPage(sourcePage);
        targetPage.setResources(sourcePage.getResources());

        stripUnusedImages(targetPage);
        stripPageLinks(targetPage);

        return targetPdf;
    }

    /**
     *  Collect the images used from a custom PDFStreamEngine (BI and DO operators)
     *  Create an empty COSDictionary
     *  Loop through the page's XObjects that are images and add them to the new COSDictionary if they were found in the PDFStreamEngine
     *  Assign the newly filled COSDictionary to the page's resource as COSName.XOBJECT
     */
    protected void stripUnusedImages(PDPage page) throws IOException {
        PDResources resources = copyResources(page);
        COSDictionary pageObjects = (COSDictionary) resources.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT);
        COSDictionary newObjects = new COSDictionary();

        Set<String> imageNames = findImageNames(page);
        Iterable<COSName> xObjectNames = resources.getXObjectNames();
        for (COSName xObjectName : xObjectNames) {
            if (resources.isImageXObject(xObjectName)) {
                Boolean used = imageNames.contains(xObjectName.getName());
                if (used) {
                    newObjects.setItem(xObjectName, pageObjects.getItem(xObjectName));
                } else {
                    log.info("Found unused image: name={}", xObjectName.getName());
                }
            } else {
                newObjects.setItem(xObjectName, pageObjects.getItem(xObjectName));
            }
        }
        resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.XOBJECT, newObjects);
        page.setResources(resources);
    }

    /**
     * It is necessary to copy the page's resources since it can be shared with other pages. We must ensure changes
     * to the resources are scoped to the current page.
     */
    protected PDResources copyResources(PDPage page) {
        return new PDResources(new COSDictionary(page.getResources().getCOSObject()));
    }

    protected Set<String> findImageNames(PDPage page) throws IOException {
        Set<String> imageNames = new HashSet<>();
        PdfImageStreamEngine engine = new PdfImageStreamEngine() {
            @Override
            void handleImage(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) {
                COSName name = (COSName) operands.get(0);
                imageNames.add(name.getName());
            }
        };
        engine.processPage(page);
        return imageNames;
    }

    /**
     * Borrowed from PDFBox page splitter
     *
     * @see org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter#processAnnotations(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage)
     */
    protected void stripPageLinks(PDPage imported) throws IOException {
        List<PDAnnotation> annotations = imported.getAnnotations();
        for (PDAnnotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (annotation instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
                PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annotation;
                PDDestination destination = link.getDestination();
                if (destination == null && link.getAction() != null) {
                    PDAction action = link.getAction();
                    if (action instanceof PDActionGoTo) {
                        destination = ((PDActionGoTo) action).getDestination();
                    }
                }
                if (destination instanceof PDPageDestination) {
                    // TODO preserve links to pages within the splitted result
                    ((PDPageDestination) destination).setPage(null);
                }
            }
            // TODO preserve links to pages within the splitted result
            annotation.setPage(null);
        }
    }

}
```

**The stream reader used to analyze the page's images:**

```
package org.apache.pdfbox.examples;

import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.Operator;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.OperatorProcessor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSBase;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDTransparencyGroup;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

abstract public class PdfImageStreamEngine extends PDFStreamEngine {

    PdfImageStreamEngine() {
        addOperator(new DrawObjectCounter());
    }

    abstract void handleImage(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands);

    protected class DrawObjectCounter extends OperatorProcessor {
        @Override
        public void process(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
            if (operands != null && isImage(operands.get(0))) {
                handleImage(operator, operands);
            }
        }

        protected Boolean isImage(COSBase base) throws IOException {
            if (!(base instanceof COSName)) {
                return false;
            }
            COSName name = (COSName)base;
            if (context.getResources().isImageXObject(name)) {
                return true;
            }
            PDXObject xObject = context.getResources().getXObject(name);
            if (xObject instanceof PDTransparencyGroup) {
                context.showTransparencyGroup((PDTransparencyGroup)xObject);
            } else if (xObject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
                context.showForm((PDFormXObject)xObject);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Do";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to handle inline images…. these don't have a name. They are really inline in the stream.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I've been swamped with work. I removed the BI counter. This was copied from a a utility class we use for other operations where BI images are important. I'll hopefully find some time to submit something back to the project soon.

Comment: You're my hero <3 <3 <3

Comment: When I open the resulting file, Adobe Reader reports an error, the file seems corrupted. Any help ?

Comment: @AndreaBorgogelliAvveduti *"When I open the resulting file, Adobe Reader reports an error, the file seems corrupted. Any help ?"* - Please make that a stack overflow question in its own right from which you can link to this question for reference, and in which you can also share a link to the PDF in question. Without the PDF we can just guess. My guess is that your PDF uses an option from very early PDF versions that allowed resources (patterns and XObjects) and annotations drawn on the page to also use the page resources...