# how to remove unused graphics from a pdf page using pdfbox in java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need to remove unused graphics/images from pages in a pdf document using pdfbox in java.
I ran into this stack overflow link: [Cleaning up unused images in PDF page resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642943/cleaning-up-unused-images-in-pdf-page-resources). this link describes exactly what I am looking for. @Tilman Hausherr and
@SakeviYokoyama exchanged ideas regarding this issue.

I downloaded the classes developed by @SakeviYokoyama but I am having an issue with the
PdfImageStreamEngine class which is used in the findImageNames method of the PageExtractor class.

The definition for the PdfImageStreamEngine class can be found in Gihub at the following URL:
https://gist.github.com/SakeviYokoyama/edeaa405bea30e3c94aaba8b073aaf2f

The issue is that the definition for the PdfImageStreamEngine class is not in the github repository; however, the definition the this class is in the Stack Overflow question. I used the definition for the class found in Stack Overflow but I am getting an error when I try to use the code in eclipse.

Eclipse complains with the following:

> "Implicit super constructor OperatorProcessor() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

I am trying to reduce the size of the split files using pdfbox.

Comment: The link you shared requires login. Based on your explanation it looks like the changes you want is not in the official library it might be a fork of the original library and the reason you are seeing the error is because you are importing the official rather than the forked one?

Comment: Make sure you're using a similar version than the one from that question,  probably 2.0.*.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it works for me. So it must be your setup. Make sure you are using the following:

- use PdfBox Version 2.0.X (I used 2.0.30)
- eclipse gives this error when you have a misconfiguration of your Java Versions. Go to Project - Preference - Java - Compiler and make sure the correct jdk/jre is installed (or go to Window - Preferences - Java - Installed JREs). For me it worked with Java 8 / 11 / 17 as a runtime
- If you are doing something special then add the code here. For me the following worked (please note that this is just rudimentary example code - so a lot of things are missing):

  ```
  try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(yourFile)){
        fis.close();

        PageExtractor extractor = new PageExtractor();
        PDDocument page = extractor.extractPage(document, 1);

        System.out.println(page.getNumberOfPages());

        document.close();
  } 
  catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```